# Not Able to Select First Button In a Div In CSS

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know why I am not able to select the first Button in the div:

```
.button-group-h button:first-child{
  background-color:yellow;
} 

<ul class="button-group-h">
    <li><button class="btn button">Button</button></li>
    <li><button class="btn button">Button</button></li> 
    <li><button class="btn button">Button</button></li>
</ul>
```

the `.button-group-h button:first-child` selector in fact selecting and affecting on all of three buttons. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `:first-child` on the `<li>`, not the button. The `<li>` elements are children of the `<ul>`, not the buttons:

```
.button-group-h li:first-child button{
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mWFSj/)**